# Loading an Image

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I read in a Game tutorial how to load images, and they did this:

```
public Image loadImage(... String ref ...) {
  ...
    URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(ref);
    BufferedImage source = ImageIO.read(url);
    GraphicsConfiguration gc = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
    Image image = gc.createCompatibleImage(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), Transparency.BITMASK);

    image.getGraphics().drawImage(source, 0, 0, null);
    return image;
}
```

This is absolutely not the best way in terms of usability and clarity (= nobody could find this way just by using their healthy brains). Why is it that complicated? Does it have to be? Why can't image loading be as easy as that:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(ref);
```

Is there an easier way if you just want to load an image in a way that Java automatically does all the default "stuff" it has to do? Is there maybe a reason the author of that code chose another way, because he wanted to achieve some non-default behaviour? When writing an answer please understand that I am looking for an easy way to solve the problem of image loading and also the ability and understanding to apply more complicated means if nessesary.

**edit:**
Also both answers are good presentations of their respective authors oppinions, until now I can't `accept` one answer, because no answer shows a simpler way and/or explains what exactly is happening.

Comment: It ensures java programmers get paid well for simple tasks :-D

Comment: perhaps the question is better placed at programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Actually, this function shouldn't compile. You return instance of `Image` class, when method declared to return `BufferedImage`.

Comment: I read that one reason the code looks that complicated is because this way the graphics chip, if existing, is used instead of the CPU to process the images. Is that correct? Which part does that? (And why is that not default behaviour?)

Comment: @erikb have you tried to skip this stuff with `GraphicsConfiguration` and return `ImageIO.read(url)`? I'm not sure, but may be it works fine.

Comment: Well, what am I skipping if I do? Maybe it displays the image but maybe I skip some behaviour that I like? Until now nobody really explained to me what these lines are doing. For example why do I need a class loader to transform a `String` to an `URL` object? What is this `GraphicsConfiguration` stuff about anyway?

Comment: Well. You need `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(ref);` in order to load image from class path. If you build your project to jar file (an images also included in jar), you need use `getResource` method to access them. Second part, about this `GraphicsConfiguration` I just don't know. If I write this function, I'd try to it without it first and see how it'd work.

Comment: @Nikita that's great information. Also this is something I was looking for, for a long time. Once we deployed a bigger class project with resources outside of the JAR, because we didn't know how to load them from inside. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, a lot more is happening here. An url is opened, the url contents are loaded in a buffer. The image is loaded from the buffer. It is converted to a device compatible bitmap.

I think 4 lines of code to do all this is pretty awesome. I don't want to sound old, but when I wanted to draw a bitmap in Ye Olde C++ in DOS, I first had to visit the library to get a book about various bitmap formats, then write about 10.000 lines of code to support only a few of them...  And then I just got a bitmap (which is about the easiest of images) on a local computer. No jpg, no networking, let alone internet, and certainly not cross platform.

If you need a lot of images to be loaded from the internet, feel free to put it in a function, like you did here. It doesn't seem weird to me that these quite unrelated functionalities aren't by default grouped in a single statement.

Comment: That's also what I thought. The code from the tutorial looks "old" in many ways. I totally understand the excitement people feel, who had to code without that years ago. But times change, and especially in IT tasks become simpler in an over proportional fashion. I think expecting a "load my image in one command" task is not too much from a strong, modern language. It just means someone has to put that effort of writing these 10.000 lines once into the JVM.

Comment: @erikb can you give example of this one function (or language), where it takes one argument and loads image from anywhere and returns image which is ready to be displayed everywhere?

Comment: @Nikita can't u imagine after seing the function the question that it is fairly easy to get the languageVM to do it? The author of the language just needs to decide on one default behaviour (which can be the same that is executed above). Giving your language user a default choice is merely a question of how much you value usability. And I still can't imagine that there is no default way in Java. Try python for example: `Image.load("anImage.gif")` (yes, you need another line to `import Image`. I also didn't count the import lines in the Java example, though)

Comment: It's possibly `Image.open` not `Image.load`. And it takes file name. URL is more universal. You can load images from file, from internet, from jar files. And in java it is almost the same `ImageIO.read(someUrl or file)`. This image processing you are doing after you load image is quite specific. I'm not sure it can be generalized.

Answer (score 2):

> Why can't image loading be as easy as that:
>
> BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(ref);

Actually, "loading an image" *IS* that easy.

GolezTrol is exactly right: there *IS* a lot happening here:

- The preceding code dynamically gets a reference to whatever graphic needs to be loaded.  You can just as easily pass a filename, a URL address, or a Java File reference (among many other possibilities).
- The subsequent code gets a reference to your graphics environment in order to display the graphic.  If you called "drawImage()" inside a GUI component's "OnPaint()" method, all of this work would already have been done for you.
- The ability to decode just about any graphics file and the ability to display it in just about any graphical environment in just one line each *IS* pretty darn awesome!
- The ability to mix'n'match where stuff comes from, how you use it, and where it goes to at will is equally awesome.

IMHO...

Answer (score 1):

I have googled a bit and I think I found the answer to your question. Optimization of the BufferedImage for given device stands behind the the Game Tutorial way of loading the image, depending on device colour depth, device resolution and colour model. There is another reason for using this version of code, which is caching of images in earlier versions of Java. In earlier versions, JVM will mark the image as managed(enables hardware acceleration) when you load it like the tutorial says, while it wont mark it as managed if it's loaded using the ImageIO.read(..). You can see the full explanation in this [post](http://flylib.com/books/en/2.235.1.51/1/). Hope this helps.